# How to stream result with mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I'm pretty rusty with sql and python since uni days.

I wonder how to read line by line of the query result instead of fetchall?

here are my current test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import csv
import mysql.connector

start_time = time.time()
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='1234',
                              host='10.0.10.100',
                              database='serverDB')

try:
 cursor = cnx.cursor()   
 cursor.execute("select * from serverDB.task")
 result = cursor.fetchall()
 with open("query.csv", "wb") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description]) # write headers
    csv_writer.writerows(result)

 for x, row in enumerate(result):
  print x
  print row
  #print result
finally:
 cnx.close()
 print "there are ", numrows, "rows"
 print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Why do you want to read the query result line by line? If you need to perform some calculations on each line before using it, you can just read them into a `list`, so that you can operate each line.

Comment: @Acepcs erm say i have 150million records, how does the list handle the huge amount of records?

Comment: @ling7334 that's after filtering

Answer (score 2):

There is a function called `fetchone`. The usage of this function is like below:

```
connect = MySQLdb.connect(......)
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('select......')
row_count = cursor.rowcount

for i in range(row_count):
    line = cursor.fetchone()    #you can operate each line
```

Comment: thanks, but that won't work for write as csv required a sequences. if if i will to run fetchone() and save it in the list, the memory usage will still be high.

Comment: Okay, so if the key problem is memory usage (since the size of your dataset is really really big), you should consider Distributed Calculation or something like dataset parallelization.

Comment: thanks! i work in a research lab where i have HDFS and Elastics Search at my disposal. My question here is how to stream mysql with python as its easy with java JCDB...